# Close smartpart view

Tags: .net, smartclient

I am developing windows Forms application, for this i am using SmartClient. Here i click workspace close('X') event at the time i want to display messageBox based on user input (OK/Cancel) i have to decide pane has to be close or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ParentForm.FormClosing` event, and set the `Cancel` property appropriately.

Subscribe to this event in the `Load` event.

Comment: How to stop form close after click close button.

Comment: @Ravi: I told you how. I dont have time to spoonfeed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using the Model-View-Presenter pattern? If you are, you can override the OnCloseView method of the form's presenter.